# What determines a note, and when we change to another one?

Tags: theory

I have begun playing the tin whistle recently, and am quite curious about something in particular.

**How is a note defined?**

My idea is that the sharp and flat versions of a note are the "boundaries" that define the note, and any frequency in this range is considered that note.

If anyone can please help guide me, mathematical answers are fine.

Comment: You probably should read about [temperament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_temperament) and the [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(music)).

Comment: I think it would be interesting to define notes by having people with absolute pitch determine what note names correspond to frequencies. Get about 50/50 disagreement on what the note name is and there's your boundary. Stuff gets more complicated if at least one absolute pitch person labels quarter tones as such.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Each note has an EXACT mathematical frequency.

But the human ear is not in sync with those exact frequencies - there's a range of frequencies that could be aurally accepted as the note.

So there are temperaments - 'equal', 'pythagorean', and syntonic temperament - to adjust the notes so they play more nicely together.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_diatonic_tuning#Syntonic_temperament_and_timbre

And indeed there are tuning systems that attempt to take this into account such as Meantone. (Mean... average).

Meantone temperament is a musical temperament, that is a tuning system, obtained by slightly compromising the fifths in order to improve the thirds. Meantone temperaments are constructed the same way as Pythagorean tuning, as a stack of equal fifths, but in meantone each fifth is narrow compared to the perfect fifth of ratio 3:2."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meantone_temperament

A simple example ... vibrato (violin, guitar, etc.) ... a judicious amount can strengthen the emotional impact of a melody ... too much can destroy it (as food spices).

A good explanation of the derivation of notes is here.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_tuning

Comment: The first part of this answer reads a bit backwards to me - I would agree that in simple terms a note is normally thought to map to an exact frequency, but can't we only put our finger on that frequency *after* factors concert pitch and intonation/temperament are taken into account?

Comment: No it doesn't.  As other comments point out,  you can pick an "exact" tonic for a given piece at a given time, but that's not constant even across professional groups in the same time period.  Further "play nicely together" is subjective, and ignores non-Western and non-classical note sets.

Comment: @topomorto  Why does it read backwards. Each note has a calculated frequency. Then it's practical frequency takes into account the factors you noted.

Comment: "Each note has a *calculated* frequency" is true - but the frequency is calculated *based on* the factors mentioned. When I read "Each note has an exact mathematical frequency" in conjunction with the idea that temperaments are to "to adjust the notes so they play more nicely together", it makes it sound to me like you're saying you can *start* with an initial, defined, frequency for each note, which (as per @CarlWitthoft's comment) isn't the case - you need to know a reference pitch, and a temperament, and possibly a key, before you can calculate a frequency. (Sorry if I'm misreading!)

Comment: @topomorto  No, it's not. It's a pythagorean calculation. I posted a link to it.

fn = f0 * (a)n 
where
f0 = the frequency of one fixed note which must be defined. A common choice is setting the A above middle C (A4) at f0 = 440 Hz.
n = the number of half steps away from the fixed note you are. If you are at a higher note, n is positive. If you are on a lower note, n is negative.
fn = the frequency of the note n half steps away.
a = (2)1/12 = the twelth root of 2 = the number which when multiplied by itself 12 times equals 2 = 1.059463094359...

Comment: "it makes it sound to me like you're saying you can start with an initial, defined, frequency for each note,"

Where did I possibly say anything like that ... I said it's calculated ... first sentence...I gave a link to the calculation ... where did I say anything remotely like 'arbitrarily assigned'.

I truly think 90% of the comments on Stack Exchange are posted by people who literally enjoy finding reasons to find fault ... Schadenfreude.

(Now lets see if I get criticized for not posting a reference to Schadenfreude.)

Comment: I agree that each note can be calculated based on an initial defined note and those other factors. I just didn't quite get the impression from your first sentence that that was what you were saying. If I'm misreading, I apologise (I'm not the downvoter BTW!) and I do agree that SE comments can seem to be populated by picky busybodies  - but one of the plus points of SE is to try to gain a level of clarity above that of other forums. Two sides of the same coin maybe?

Comment: "but one of the plus points of SE is to try to gain a level of clarity above that of other forums"

Show me a single instance where that was successful. Once I posted a question asking why some melodies are more appealing than others ... what is the structure of a 'musical hook' ... about a dozen comments stating musical hook is subjective and I need to give a scientific definition.

That is ... 100% ... absurd.

Comment: @RandyZeitman Let's face it, no-one's on Stack Exchange because it's the most fun you can have on the internet; if SE didn't *often* get the facts straighter than other sites, then neither you, nor I, nor anyone else would bother being members here. Part of getting those facts straight *does* come from being a bit nit-picky sometimes; in some cases I disagree with comments that are made on my answers; other times, I appreciate them because they give me a chance to sharpen up my own thoughts. If in this case you don't think my comments are helpful I can only apologise again...

Comment: "then neither you, nor I, nor anyone else would bother being members here"

?... please check your address for my brain ... it's not what I think and no reason to think "anyone else" would think as you do.

I absolutely joined SE for having fun (the anticipation of getting answers because here I wasn't limited to how I posted the question).

Comment: You said that you thought 90% of comments are posted by people who enjoy finding reasons to find fault (in this case, presumably including me). I'm just saying that I think that's a little unfair. From https://music.stackexchange.com/tour/ - "This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat. Good answers are voted up and rise to the top." So there is a focus on making answers (and questions) as clear (and correct) as possible.

Comment: The top answer at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work says "Comments are often used to ask for clarification on, suggest corrections to, and provide meta-information about posts". Again I'll say that I *do* agree with you that there's some needless nit-picking that goes on, but IMO it shows that well-intentioned suggestions and clarifications are in the spirit of what the site is about.

Comment: And if people are looking to not be limited on how they post questions and answers - again, for better or worse, that's not (IMHO) quite what's on offer here. Indeed, there's a whole forum, [meta],(https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/) dedicated to talking about *how* people should write questions and answers on the main site!

Comment: @topomorto I was speaking about length of question, not format.

Answer (score 1):

> How is a note defined?

Interesting question, and perhaps not one that has an obvious answer.

Even assuming we're talking about current western music culture, I think you could answer from a few different perspectives.

If assume that we're talking about named notes in a given key - for example, in C major, the notes C-D-E-F-G-A-B - then your definition of the sharp and flat versions of a note being the "boundaries" that define the note could make sense - APART from the two places in the scale where the unaltered notes are only a semitone apart - that is, the boundary between B and C, and between E and F. In other words, C flat *is* B*, but we can't really clam B as being C's territory, 'cos.... it's B! In these cases, we might want to give each note a 'territory' of 50 *cents* on the 'narrow' side of the note (a cent is 1/100th of a semitone).

On the other hand, if by 'note' we mean one of the 12 'slots' per octave that the chromatic (12-tone) scale allows, then in each case we could give each note a territory of 50 cents either side, *assuming* equal temperament. However, equal temperament is not the only temperament available - different temperaments of the scale will move our boundaries up and down a bit.

And when we consider temperaments, it leads me on to the other way we could interpret this question, which is (as per Randy's answer) that a note, in a given temperament, assuming a particular concert pitch, *isn't* really considered to inhabit a *range* of frequencies at all, but instead to map to a specific frequency. Of course this might not always be the frequency that is actually hit in performance, due to inaccuracy or deliberate application of techniques such as vibrato.


<sub>*You might say that it doesn't make sense to talk about C flat in the key of C, but I'm trying to answer 'in the spirit of the question'.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

If there is to be a boundary between (say) F and F#, it will be halfway between F and F#.   That is where we would stop considering it an out of tune F (too sharp) and an out of tune F# (too flat).